# Calling PL/pgSQL function ignoring results

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I like to call a stored PL/pgSQL function the same way as with `PERFORM` ignoring the results, but from plain SQL. How can i achive this? I'm currently using `SELECT` to execute the function, but this prints data on the console what i don't need.

I thought about disabling client output for specific `SELECT` statements, but i can't find any client settings for this. Maybe there's a better way to do this kind of calls.

Comment: What client are you using (psql, ...) or is this inside a (Java) program?

Comment: I use this in a sql script which is being executed by the `psql` client, passing the filename with the `-f` switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in plain sql. What you can do though, is make the function not return anything.

Comment: Changed my function header to return nothing (`RETURNS integer` -> `RETURNS void`), but if i call the function i still get a two liner:

  add_translation 
 -----------------
  
 (1 row)

My function manipulates a translation string in a table (updates it or insert it as new).

Comment: make the function return setof something (int4 for example), and then don't return anything. it will be as close to "doesn't return anything" as possible

Comment: I did what you suggested, changed `RETURNS void` to `RETURNS setof int4` and removed all RETURN lines from the function. I still get the one column table but this time with (0 rows) at the end.

Comment: Well, sure. You run the query. If you want to get rid of returnset headers and summary, add "\t" before your queries, or run psql with -t option.

Comment: A bit more detailed answer, with examples: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/05/03/tips-n-tricks-return-nothing-from-plpgsql-function/

Comment: Great link, thank you! I can hide all text output this way, but psql still prints a new line with every select. Sadly this is still not okay for a log file. :(

Comment: Looks like this did the trick. :)

I'm trying to enable these modes from a runnig script (like `SET tuples_only=true`) however i can't do that. I guess they can be se on the command line only.

Comment: of course you can set it in script, but you can't use SQL "set" you have to use psql's \pset. \pset format unaligned and \pset tuples_only - more information in manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty hack, i just came up with; 
background is, i need to call a function, but specify an UPDATE, not a SELECT ...maybe your background is the same...
So I specified my UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE sometable_doesnt_matter 
SET some_comlumn=some_comlumn 
WHERE (select my_function = 1);
```

And my function always returns the integer 1.

Ofc i'm going to change the code so that it will also work with a SELECT, but right now, as a hotfix, this works for me.